# Integrate Rollbar in XCode to upload dSYM files: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: python, ios, xcode, rollbar

I have integrated Rollbar service in my iOS Swift App with XCode. As on my other apps I integrate the dYM upload to Rollbar with the officially documented "Run script" phase.

Changed Shell to `/usr/bin/python` (and `/usr/bin/python` works). Edited the script itself as described [here](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-ios/#symbolication-using-dsym-files).

But XCode exists on build with error

```
File "xxx/Debug-iphoneos/Append.build/Script-E84633381E362A3A0085BB75.sh", line 8
exit(0)
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

But why is `/bin/sh` used with my python code? For sure, this cannot work – but XCode uses `/bin/sh` instead of `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Hey Kevin, sorry to reach out to you like this, but I saw your question about AVAssetExportSession and was wondering if you found a solution? I am totally stumped by this and any help would be greatly appreciated!  Heres my email: nadalalyafaie@gmail.com . Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

I have pasted the code of the Python snippet with ***Paste and Preserve Formatting*** and now it works fine.